# Rails form select dropdown show the value stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dropdown

I have a helper with us state names and abbreviations and am successfully using this form in an edit profile view to render the states in a dropdown and save a state to the db when the user selects and submits the form.

```
<%= f.label :State %>
  <%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states), :include_blank => "Please Select") %>
```

Once my form saves and reloads, even though the state saved to the db, the form still shows "Please Select", so I have tried this:

```
  <%= f.label :State %>
      <%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states), selected: @clinician_profile.state) %>
```

But then it shows the first state in the helper array (Alabama) rather than the saved state.

How can I have it both show "Please Select" when no value is in the db but show the appropriate state once the user has already selected it?

Thanks for any help!
Here is the very top of my form:

```
<%= form_for(@clinician_profile) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class ClinicianProfilesController < ApplicationController
def edit
    @clinician_profile = current_user.clinician_profile
end

def index
end

def show

end

def create
end

def update
@clinician_profile = current_user.clinician_profile 
if @clinician_profile.update_attributes(clinician_profile_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
    redirect_to edit_clinician_profile_path(current_user)
else
    render 'edit'
    end
end


private

        def clinician_profile_params
            params.require(:clinician_profile).permit(:address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, 
                :accepting_patients, :rate, :license_number, :license_state, :years_licensed, :years_practicing, 
                :school, :year_graduated, :accepts_insurance, :sliding_scale, :bio, :website, insurance_ids: [], race_ids: [], language_ids: [])

end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when using [*options_for_select*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) with `select`, the `selected` option should be included as an argument for `options_for_select`. Also you should use `prompt` instead of `include_blank` So your code should look like below

```
<%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, selected: @clinician_profile.state), prompt: "Please Select") %>
```

Answer (score -1):

`options_for_select` takes two arguments (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) where the second argument is `nil` by default.

You need to pass the value of the state selected as a second argument of `options_for_select(us_states, selected: @clinician_profile.state`.